# Tkinter Python- a frame with scrollbar, canvas, and button(scrollbar doesn't work)

Tags: python, button, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

First, I would like to thanks for your help in advance since this question bothers me for a long time. After searching on the internet, I still can't find the answer that fits to this problem.

The idea is to have a frame as a base window. Then inside the frame I create a canvas to place multiple buttons that's the reason for the scrollbar.

I manage to make the scrollbar shows up however it doesn't have any function. **(third part of the code)**
I tried to look up to similar questions but most of the time the widgets are all labels not buttons.

Here's the code/picture and what it looks like.
Thank you so much!!!!!

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def frontpage():
    #1. window setup
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Title")                       
    screenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()      
    screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()    
    w = 1200                                    
    h = 680                                     
    x = (screenWidth - w) / 2                   
    y = (screenHeight - h ) / 4                 
    root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w,h,x,y))
    
    #2. window background 
    image = Image.open("secondpage/sec.gif")
    yellowstone = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label = tk.Label(root,image=yellowstone)
    label.pack()
    
    #3.frame with canvas and scrollbar
    canvas_frame = tk.Frame(root)                           #frame set up
    canvas_frame.place(x=150,y=95)
    canvas_frame_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(canvas_frame)     #scrollbar set up
    canvas_frame_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(canvas_frame, width=898, height=490,bd=0,bg='#f9ca7c') #canvas set up
    canvas.pack()                                          
    
    #4.button design button picture size=100*100
    person_name_font= tkFont.Font(size=5, weight="bold") #font design
    front_p1_pic = tk.PhotoImage(file="secondpage/p1.gif") # button image
    front_p1 = tk.Button(canvas_frame,image= front_p1_pic,compound=tk.TOP,font= person_name_font)
    front_p2 = tk.Button(canvas_frame,image= front_p1_pic,compound=tk.TOP,font= person_name_font)
    
    #4-1.button place
    front_p1.place(x=56,y=30,width=100,height=100)
    front_p2.place(x=232,y=30,width=100,height=100)
    root.mainloop()
    
frontpage()
```

The photo 1 is what it looks like, photo 2 and 3 are the background and the image for the button
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6rLY.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M8su.gif [3]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0WXi.gif

Comment: There is no difference in behavior between labels and buttons with respect to scrolling.

Comment: If you want to scroll those buttons, you should not use `place()` on them.  You should create an internal frame and use `canvas.create_window()` to put the frame inside the canvas.  Then pack/grid those buttons inside that internal frame.  You should also update the `scrollregion` when the size of the internal frame is changed.

Comment: Trying to use procedural code to create a tkinter app, when you also intend to create custom complex/combination widgets, generally becomes a huge mess.  Imagine I gave you a completed car and let's assume that the car represents a `class`, you would immediately recognize it as a car and should have no problem operating it. Now, Imagine I gave you every single PIECE of a car ~ that's your procedural code. You've dumped all the parts of a "car" right in the middle of everything else you are doing, and wonder why you can't put it together and make it run. Use classes for custom complex widgets.

Comment: There's another thing to consider here. Is this the one and only time you are ever going to need a scrollable frame? Probably not. What are you going to do the next time you need one ... hunt down the procedural version and copy/paste/modify it every time? If you turn it into a class, you can simply import and use it.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you so much for the information!

Comment: @acw1668 I'll try to set it up with this idea! it's really useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelGuidry Oh I should really create a class for it since there's definitely lot of uses of it! Working on it at the moment ^^. Thank you for your advice Michael !

Comment: I can give you a hint that you may want/need. Extend `tk.Frame`, put your canvas and scrollbar in it, and then stick your "scrollable frame" in the canvas. Your final product should just be a `tk.Frame` that you've put a bunch of stuff in. It should still work like a `tk.Frame` and accept all the same arguments as a `tk.Frame`. If there is one single thing that a `tk.Frame` can do that your `ScrollableFrame` can't ... you messed up.

Comment: If you want to "cheat", I shared a completely functional `ScrollableFrame` in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/63946783/10292330