# Tkinter – Auto-resizing images in a scrollable grid

Tags: python, tkinter

Here's my vision:

I have a collection of photos that I would like to display in a simple window in grid format. Each row would have 5 images in it. As I resize the window, I want the photos to automatically resize to fit an optimal new grid cell size. I consider an optimal grid to have equally-sized cells across the entire grid.

---

I have some code that can almost do this. I borrowed and modified code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63946783/11106258) but there are a couple problems. First, here's the full code:

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk
from typing import Iterable
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageOps


class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, scrollspeed=5, r=0, c=0, rspan=1, cspan=1, grid={}, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **{'width': 400, 'height': 300, **kwargs})

        # __GRID
        self.grid(**{'row': r, 'column': c, 'rowspan': rspan, 'columnspan': cspan, 'sticky': 'nswe', **grid})

        # allow user to set width and/or height
        if {'width', 'height'} & {*kwargs}:
            self.grid_propagate(0)

        # give this widget weight on the master grid
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)

        # give self.frame weight on this grid
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # _WIDGETS
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, bg=self['bg'], highlightthickness=0, yscrollincrement=scrollspeed)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, **kwargs)
        self.frame_id = self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        vsb.configure(command=self.canvas.yview)

        # attach scrollbar to canvas
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        # _BINDS
        # canvas resize
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.on_canvas_configure)
        # frame resize
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_frame_configure)
        # scroll wheel
        self.canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.on_mousewheel)

    # makes frame width match canvas width
    def on_canvas_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.frame_id, width=event.width)

    # when frame dimensions change pass the area to the canvas scroll region
    def on_frame_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    # add scrollwheel feature
    def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-event.delta / abs(event.delta)), 'units')

    # configure self.frame row(s)
    def rowcfg(self, index, **options):
        index = index if isinstance(index, Iterable) else [index]
        for i in index:
            self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(i, **options)
        # so this can be used inline
        return self

    # configure self.frame column(s)
    def colcfg(self, index, **options):
        index = index if isinstance(index, Iterable) else [index]
        for i in index:
            self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, **options)
        # so this can be used inline
        return self


class AuxiliaryWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        # if you reconsider things, you can accomplish more with less
        labels = ["this is a sort of long label",
                  "this is another label",
                  "Other information: blah blah blah blah"]

        for i, text in enumerate(labels):
            ttk.Label(self, text=text).grid(row=0, column=i)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        # doing it this way the text will always fit the display as long as you give it enough height to work with
        instr = tk.Text(self, height=3, wrap='word', bg='gray94', font='Arial 8 bold', bd=0, relief='flat')
        instr.insert('1.0', ' '.join(['instructions'] * 20))
        instr.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, sticky='nswe')

        # instantiate the scrollframe, configure the first 5 columns and return the frame. it's inline mania! :p
        self.scrollframe = ScrollFrame(self, 10, 2, 0, cspan=3).colcfg(range(5), weight=1).frame

        self.fillScrollRegion()

        # why store a reference to this? Do you intend to change/delete it later?
        ttk.Button(self, text="Do Something", command=self.do).grid(row=3, columnspan=3, sticky='ew')

    def fillScrollRegion(self):
        """fills scrollable region with label widgets"""
        base_dir = "/dir/with/my/jpg/images"
        images = sorted([os.path.join(base_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(base_dir)])
        self.img_artifacts = []

        num_cols = 5
        for i in range(len(images)):
            img = Image.open(images[i])
            img = ImageOps.exif_transpose(img)
            tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            self.img_artifacts.append(tkimg)
            lbl = ttk.Label(self.scrollframe, image=tkimg, anchor="center")
            lbl.grid(row=i // num_cols, column=i % num_cols, sticky='nsew')
            lbl.bind("<Configure>", lambda e, lbl=lbl, img=img: self.resize_img(e, lbl, img))


    def resize_img(self, event, label, img):
        bounds = (label.winfo_width(), round(label.winfo_height()))
        vert_scale = bounds[1] / img.height
        horiz_scale = bounds[0] / img.width
        scale = min(horiz_scale, vert_scale)
        new_dims = (round(scale * img.width), round(scale * img.height))
        img = img.resize(new_dims)
        tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.img_artifacts.append(tkimg)
        label.config(image=tkimg)
        print(f"Label: {label} | Event: {event} | Bounds: {bounds} | New dims: {new_dims}")


    def do(self):
        pass


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('600x300+600+200')
        self.title('This Is A Title Probably Or Something')  # :D

        aux = AuxiliaryWindow(self)
        aux.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.mainloop()


Root() if __name__ == "__main__" else None
```

Here are the issues:

1. It is *very* slow. With 12 images, it takes several seconds (15+) to actually start. It is also very laggy when scrolling or resizing the window.
2. The cells are not the same size. Some of my pictures were taken in landscape format, others in portrait (i.e. horizontal vs vertical being the long side). Tkinter optimizes the label size here by making a column narrower if there is only/mostly vertically-oriented photos, and then they look giant next to the landscape photos.

Comment: I'm sorry is that a request for code or do you have a real question where you want to gain a better understanding of something in your code?

Comment: The very slow startup is because you are binding to `"<Configure>"` on the images too early. Replace that line with `lbl.after(100, lbl.bind, "<Configure>", lambda e, lbl=lbl, img=img: self.resize_img(e, lbl, img))` for better startup time.

Comment: @Thingamabobs I am guessing that OP wants to know why the code takes 15+ seconds to start and why the images aren't being resized as OP wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resize the image in a label inside a callback that is executed whenever the label is resized may cause recursive issue.  So I would suggest to perform the resize of images after `ScrollFrame.frame` is resized instead:

- pass a callback to `ScrollFrame.__init__()` that will be executed once after `ScrollFrame.frame` is resized (inside `ScrollFrame.on_canvas_configure()`)
- the callback is `AuxiliaryWindow.resize_images()` (it is rewritten)

Also the labels created inside `AuxiliaryWindow.fillScrollRegion()` will not show image initially.  The image is stored as an attribute of the label initially.

Function `AuxiliaryWindow.resize_image()` will be passed the resized width of the frame as an argument.

Below is the updated code:

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk
from typing import Iterable
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageOps

class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, scrollspeed=5, r=0, c=0, rspan=1, cspan=1, grid={}, **kwargs):
        ### get the resize callback
        self.resize_images_func = kwargs.pop("resize_images_func", None)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **{'width': 400, 'height': 300, **kwargs})

        # __GRID
        self.grid(**{'row': r, 'column': c, 'rowspan': rspan, 'columnspan': cspan, 'sticky': 'nswe', **grid})

        # allow user to set width and/or height
        if {'width', 'height'} & {*kwargs}:
            self.grid_propagate(0)

        # give this widget weight on the master grid
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)

        # give self.frame weight on this grid
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # _WIDGETS
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, bg=self['bg'], highlightthickness=0, yscrollincrement=scrollspeed)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, **kwargs)
        self.frame_id = self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        vsb.configure(command=self.canvas.yview)

        # attach scrollbar to canvas
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        # _BINDS
        # canvas resize
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.on_canvas_configure)
        # frame resize
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_frame_configure)
        # scroll wheel
        self.canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.on_mousewheel)

        ### for storing the ID returned by .after()
        self.task = None   

    # makes frame width match canvas width
    def on_canvas_configure(self, event):
        # function to do the final resize task
        def final_update(width):
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.frame_id, width=width)
            if self.resize_images_func:
                self.resize_images_func(width)
            self.task = None

        if self.task:
            self.after_cancel(self.task)
        # don't do resize task during resizing the canvas to improve performance
        # so delay the task using .after()
        self.task = self.after(50, final_update, event.width)

    # when frame dimensions change pass the area to the canvas scroll region
    def on_frame_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    # add scrollwheel feature
    def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-event.delta / abs(event.delta)), 'units')

    # configure self.frame row(s)
    def rowcfg(self, index, **options):
        index = index if isinstance(index, Iterable) else [index]
        for i in index:
            self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(i, **options)
        # so this can be used inline
        return self

    # configure self.frame column(s)
    def colcfg(self, index, **options):
        index = index if isinstance(index, Iterable) else [index]
        for i in index:
            self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, **options)
        # so this can be used inline
        return self


class AuxiliaryWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        # if you reconsider things, you can accomplish more with less
        labels = ["this is a sort of long label",
                  "this is another label",
                  "Other information: blah blah blah blah"]

        for i, text in enumerate(labels):
            ttk.Label(self, text=text).grid(row=0, column=i)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        # doing it this way the text will always fit the display as long as you give it enough height to work with
        instr = tk.Text(self, height=3, wrap='word', bg='gray94', font='Arial 8 bold', bd=0, relief='flat')
        instr.insert('1.0', ' '.join(['instructions'] * 20))
        instr.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, sticky='nswe')

        # instantiate the scrollframe, configure the first 5 columns and return the frame. it's inline mania! :p
        self.scrollframe = ScrollFrame(self, 10, 2, 0, cspan=3,
                                       ### pass resize_images() as argument "resize_images_func"
                                       resize_images_func=self.resize_images).colcfg(range(5), weight=1).frame

        self.fillScrollRegion()

        # why store a reference to this? Do you intend to change/delete it later?
        ttk.Button(self, text="Do Something", command=self.do).grid(row=3, columnspan=3, sticky='ew')

    def fillScrollRegion(self):
        """fills scrollable region with label widgets"""
        base_dir = "/dir/with/my/jpg/images"
        images = sorted([os.path.join(base_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(base_dir)])

        ### use instance variable to store the number of columns
        self.num_cols = 5
        for i in range(len(images)):
            row, col = divmod(i, self.num_cols)
            img = Image.open(images[i])
            img = ImageOps.exif_transpose(img)
            ### just create a label without showing the image initially
            lbl = ttk.Label(self.scrollframe, anchor="center")
            lbl.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='nsew')
            lbl.image = img  ### save the original image for later resize

    def resize_images(self, width):
        width -= self.num_cols * 4   # cater border and hightlight of labels
        ### calculate the grid size
        img_width = width // self.num_cols
        ### go through all the labels
        for lbl in self.scrollframe.winfo_children():
            ### resize the image keeping the aspect ratio
            img = ImageOps.contain(lbl.image, (img_width, img_width))
            ### show the image
            lbl.tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            lbl.config(image=lbl.tkimg)

    def do(self):
        pass


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('600x300+600+200')
        self.title('This Is A Title Probably Or Something')  # :D

        aux = AuxiliaryWindow(self)
        aux.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.mainloop()


Root() if __name__ == "__main__" else None
```

Comment: Your code is way more elegant than mine +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageOps
from typing import Iterable
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter as tk
import os


class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, scrollspeed=5, r=0, c=0, rspan=1, cspan=1, grid={}, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **{'width': 400, 'height': 300, **kwargs})

        # __GRID
        self.grid(**{'row': r, 'column': c, 'rowspan': rspan, 'columnspan': cspan, 'sticky': 'nswe', **grid})

        # allow user to set width and/or height
        if {'width', 'height'} & {*kwargs}:
            self.grid_propagate(0)

        # give this widget weight on the master grid
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)

        # give self.frame weight on this grid
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # _WIDGETS
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, bg=self['bg'], highlightthickness=0, yscrollincrement=scrollspeed)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, **kwargs)
        self.frame_id = self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        vsb.configure(command=self.canvas.yview)

        # attach scrollbar to canvas
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        # _BINDS
        # canvas resize
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.on_canvas_configure)
        # frame resize
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_frame_configure)
        # scroll wheel
        self.canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.on_mousewheel)

    # makes frame width match canvas width
    def on_canvas_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.frame_id, width=event.width)
        self.frame.config(height=event.height, width=event.width)

    # when frame dimensions change pass the area to the canvas scroll region
    def on_frame_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    # add scrollwheel feature
    def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-event.delta / abs(event.delta)), 'units')

    # configure self.frame row(s)
    def rowcfg(self, index, **options):
        index = index if isinstance(index, Iterable) else [index]
        for i in index:
            self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(i, **options)
        # so this can be used inline
        return self

    # configure self.frame column(s)
    def colcfg(self, index, **options):
        index = index if isinstance(index, Iterable) else [index]
        for i in index:
            self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, **options)
        # so this can be used inline
        return self


class AuxiliaryWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        # if you reconsider things, you can accomplish more with less
        labels = ["this is a sort of long label",
                  "this is another label",
                  "Other information: blah blah blah blah"]

        for i, text in enumerate(labels):
            ttk.Label(self, text=text).grid(row=0, column=i)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        # doing it this way the text will always fit the display as long as you give it enough height to work with
        instr = tk.Text(self, height=3, wrap='word', bg='gray94', font='Arial 8 bold', bd=0, relief='flat')
        instr.insert('1.0', ' '.join(['instructions'] * 20))
        instr.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, sticky='nswe')

        num_cols = 5
        # instantiate the scrollframe, configure the first 5 columns and return the frame. it's inline mania! :p
        self.scrollframe = ScrollFrame(self, 10, 2, 0, cspan=3, bd=0, highlightthickness=0).colcfg(range(num_cols), weight=1).frame

        self.fillScrollRegion(num_cols)

        # why store a reference to this? Do you intend to change/delete it later?
        ttk.Button(self, text="Do Something", command=self.do).grid(row=3, columnspan=3, sticky='ew')

    def fillScrollRegion(self, num_cols):
        """fills scrollable region with label widgets"""
        base_dir = "imgs"
        images = sorted(os.path.join(base_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(base_dir))

        for i in range(len(images)):
            img = Image.open(images[i])
            img = ImageOps.exif_transpose(img)
            tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            f = tk.Frame(self.scrollframe, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
            f.pack_propagate(False)
            lbl = ttk.Label(f, image=tkimg, anchor="center")
            lbl.img = tkimg
            lbl.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
            f.grid(row=i//num_cols, column=i%num_cols, sticky="news")
            f.bind("<Configure>", lambda e, lbl=lbl, img=img: self.resize_img(e, lbl, img))

    def resize_img(self, event, label, img):
        bounds = event.width, event.height
        if bounds == (1,1):
            return # Don't do anything if we are still loading the window
        vert_scale = float("inf") # bounds[1] / img.height
        horiz_scale = bounds[0] / img.width
        scale = min(horiz_scale, vert_scale)
        new_dims = (round(scale * img.width), round(scale * img.height))
        img = img.resize(new_dims)
        label.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        label.config(image=label.img)
        event.widget.config(height=new_dims[1])
        print(f"Label: {label} | Event: {event} | Bounds: {bounds} | New dims: {new_dims}")


    def do(self):
        pass


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('600x300+600+200')
        self.title('This Is A Title Probably Or Something')  # :D
        self.aux = AuxiliaryWindow(self)
        self.aux.pack(expand=True, fill="both")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

The things I changed:

- I added `self.frame.config(height=event.height, width=event.width)` to `on_canvas_configure` so that the frame can be resized as the canvas is resized
- I removed the `img_artifacts` variable and made each label store its own `PhotoImage` so that we don't have a list that can grow infinitely.
- I moved the `.mainloop()` to outside of the class to make it easier for me to access the `Root` object from the global scope.

The important changes:

- I moved each image label to its own frame. I call `.pack_propagate(False)` on those frames so that they their size isn't controlled by the image (the frame should control the image size instead)
- I changed the `resize_img` method accordingly.

Notes:

- The program will still be laggy when resizing the window because of the `print`s and resizes that need to be executed. I suggest aggregating the resizes to make it easier on the CPU.